# I killed a naturally spawning iron golem. How do I fix my village reputation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There was an Iron Golem that was affecting my spawn rates in my farm, and so now my village reputation has been reduced. What is the best way to improve my village reputation in 1.13.2?

Comment: If you already know about the reputation system, how come that you don't know the answer to this already? The wiki tells you what increases it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Minecraft wiki: "Trading with a villager for the last offer slot on their list" will increase your reputation by 1. Since you killed the Iron Golem, that decreased your reputation by 5, so repeat the action above 5 times and you should be back to what reputation you had before.